# Renaming the current directory from a shell - possible?

Tags: shell, rename

Is it possible to rename the current working directory from within a shell (Bash in my particular case)? If I attempt to do this the straightforward way, I end up with an error:

```
nathan@nathan-desktop:/tmp/test$ mv . test2
mv: cannot move ‘.’ to ‘test2’: Device or resource busy
```

Is there another way to do this without changing the current directory? I realize that I can easily accomplish this by changing to the parent directory, but I'm curious if this is necessary. After all, if I rename the directory from another shell, I can still create files in the original shell afterwards.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, but you have to refer to the directory by name, not by using the `.` notation. You can use a relative path, it just has to end with something other than `.` or `..`:

```
/tmp/test$ mv ../test ../test2
/tmp/test$ pwd
/tmp/test
/tmp/test$ pwd -P
/tmp/test2
```

You can use an absolute path:

```
/tmp/test$ cd -P .
/tmp/test2$ mv "$PWD" "${PWD%/*}/test3"
/tmp/test2$
```

Similarly, `rmdir .` won't ever work, but `rmdir "$PWD"` does.

Comment: Perfect... exactly the answer I was hoping for.

Comment: The basic issue is that you're not allowed to remove or rename the special "." and ".." names.

Answer (score 3):

As in @Gilles answer but using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) for brevity:

```bash
mv ../{test,test2}
```

Answer (score 1):

And it depends on how you define “changing the current directory”.

```
/tmp/test$ (cd .. && mv test test2)
/tmp/test$ pwd
/tmp/test
/tmp/test$ pwd -P
/tmp/test2
```

spawns a subshell and changes the current directory in the subshell,
but leaves your primary shell where it was.